Does Cognito provide the Id token that is returned by Google?
I'm currently using Cognito preSignUp trigger to store users in my own database. To do so, I want to access the ID token that is generated by Google and save it in the database but I can't access it. I have found resources that state that identities attribute in the event has the ID token but Imy event doesn't have such an attribute.
So my question is does Cognito provide the Id token that is returned by Google or there is no way for me to access it?
Notes:

The event has all the data that I require and mapped (firstName,
LastName,etc...)
My enabled scopes are: email, openid, profile

Thank you in advance!
